# html code for twitter button is wrong

Tags: html

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @TwitterDev</a><script async      src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Error parsing XML, line 8, column 133: Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character. How do I fix? sorry, I have very little html background

Comment: This is HTML, not XML ... did you save it incorrectly as an `*.xml` instead of an `*.html` file?

Comment: I was using blogger and I pasted the html from twitter button help. The error message given on blogger was xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to add a Twitter Follow button to your blogger website. Here is the snippet for it.

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitterDev" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" data-size="large">Follow @twitterDev</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Replace the `twitterDev` keyword with your twitter username and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

---

Follow @PromoLITHIUM2018

### idgets.js" charset="utf-8">

Comment: It's a very unclear answer, you should explain the solution.